# Change Module Header name in phpfox

Tags: module, phpfox

I am developing one web site using phpfox tool. In dashboard i want to change Activity Feed heading into something different. How i can able change that heading? I tried using Block Manager title change option it is not reflected in page. Please help me to change header name... I am new to phpfox if you have any online reference link for learn phpfox pls send link also. Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go to your site's admin area

   admincp->Extensions->Language->Phrase Manager
2. Search for'Activity Feed'
3. From here you can change the title of Activity Feed